# Nesting Custom Classes/XIB's with Interface Builder

Tags: objective-c, iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, uikit, interface-builder

I'll try to make this as short as I can.

I wrote a custom class that extends UIView with a couple of IBOutlet properties, and it has a XIB associated with it where those IBOutlets are linked to.

I then want to take that class, embed it in some other XIB (for example, a table cell), and just have it work.

It seems that when I embed that custom class in the new XIB, it does not recognize the original XIB I associated with it, so it asks for me to reset the IBOutlets to interface elements on the new XIB. This is lame.

Does anyone understand what I am trying to do and have a good approach?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's how I managed to make this work:

**In Interface Builder**
Open your outer nib and do this:

- Add a UIView to define the space where you want your inner nib to display.
- Add a UIViewController object from the library, set its Nib Name property to the name of your inner nib file (without the extension).
- Create IBOutlets for these two items in your outer view controller and wire them up. (I'll refer to them as *innerView* and *innerViewController*.)
- Do not connect any of the IBOutlets defined in your inner view controller to anything in your outer nib file, just leave them unconnected.

**In Xcode**
In your outer view controller's *viewDidLoad* method, add these two lines:

```
[self.innerView addSubview:self.innerViewController.view];
self.innerViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.innerView.frame.size.width, self.innerView.frame.size.height);
```

If your outer nib is a custom UITableViewCell, put those lines in your *awakeFromNib* method instead.

Build & Run!

Comment: It works the same way on OS X, just replace the UI classes with their NS counterparts.

Comment: This is the best approach I have found for nesting Xibs: https://medium.com/flawless-app-stories/how-to-reuse-complex-xib-designed-views-in-storyboards-using-modern-swift-generics-property-e0b7c06b07a6

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're simply putting UIViews in a nib for use by a UIViewController that's purely in code. Apple calls this a [detached nib file](http://developer.apple.com/IPhone/library/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/BasicViewControllers/BasicViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH101-SW32).

Follow the guide I linked to for details and example of how to get this to work.

Regarding embedding a view inside another in Interface Builder, you need to [add a UIView element from the Library](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/IB_UserGuide/EditingNibFileObjects/EditingNibFileObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005344-CH12-SW21) into the parent view, and [set its class in the Inspector](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/IB_UserGuide/CodeIntegration/CodeIntegration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005344-CH18-SW8). Once the class of the embedded view is set, your IBOutlets should be visible.

Comment: That first sentence isn't quite what I am doing. The class itself is a UIView, and it contains a UIImageView and a UIActivityIndicator. That last sentence is right, but unfortunately it doesn't behave correctly. It jacks up the IBOutlets.