# iOS: Owner is nil in subview

Tags: ios, ios6, uiviewcontroller, uitextfield, nested-views

I have a UIViewController nested within another view ([Nested view instruction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1750735/nesting-custom-classes-xibs-with-interface-builder)). When I'm trying to link a text field within the subview to it's owner (inner view), it's causing the app to terminate when the view is initialized. Based on my research online, it seems that the cause if that the owner is nil.

> 2013-08-26 11:54:43.909 Toovia[72732:a0b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key keywordsField.'

I'm very new to iOS development (4 days) and I just couldn't figure out how to solve this problem. Any help is appreciative. I hope it's just a simple fix.

[image]

Comment: if you have xib/storyboards files - check your connections (f.e keywordsField field connection)

Comment: Connections looks fine. Everything is linked as expected (as much as I know). If I unlink the text field, the app is able to run just fine. When I link it, it fails to load the parent view.

Comment: Ok, the issue wasn't the linking part. It's actually selecting the custom class for the subview.